# How to re-authenticate a user with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried to re-authenticate a user with firebase but I can't seem to get it to work. I have looked at the firebase documentation but it wasn't helping me. Here is what I got.

```
var emailTextField: UITextField!
var currentPasswordTextfield: UITextField!

let reEnterInfo = UIAlertController(title: "Re-Enter Email and Password", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        reEnterInfo.addTextField(configurationHandler: emailTextField)
        reEnterInfo.addTextField(configurationHandler: currentPasswordTextfield)
        let reSignInButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Re-Sign In", style: .default, handler: self.reSignIn)
        reEnterInfo.addAction(reSignInButton)
        self.present(reEnterInfo, animated: true, completion: nil)

  func reSignIn(alert: UIAlertAction!)
  {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let credential: AuthCredential

    user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
        if error != nil {

        } else {

        }
   }
}
```

I am trying to re-authenticate to change the user password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide the actual credential:

```
let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
```

Comment: How do I get the email and password so the user can be authenticated again?